# How to search amongst DONE items (either archived or not)

Tags: org-agenda, search

I am new to Emacs and wonder how it is possible to search a `DONE` item.
I archive my `DONE` items from agenda files once every couple months. So some `DONE` items are in the agenda files themselves and some are in archived files.

How can I search across agenda and archived files?

Comment: Does `v A` in the agenda do what you want?

Comment: Well, I need to search amongst the results. With that [v A] I could view the DONE items as I browse, but if the item I look for is 10 years ago... then it would take a while! :)

Comment: Have youi tried it? I got things from 10 years ago in no time at all. But I have a small number of agenda files (really three that see active duty, but fewer than 20 altogether: I really need to clean up and get rid of the unused ones...) and they are relatively small (less than 1.5MB altogether), so it may not apply to your case. But I think you should try and see: you might be pleasantly surprised - and even if the results are unacceptable,  you can profile the code and find out where it's spending its time and either optimize the code or change your strategy (depending on what you find).

Comment: Thanks, but really, the use I want to give it is to be able to search for a DONE items for which I have no idea when it may have occured. So browsing is very manual.

Comment: You can use the agenda for searching: see [Matching Tags and Properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties). There is also a third-party search engine, [org-ql](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql) that implements a query language with more capabilities.